# jQuery - iterate siblings and identify button

Tags: jquery

I have a number of `<select>` objects that I need to handle their `change()` events. I don't have complete control over the DOM because a plugin is doing some things at run time to make it more complex. As a result, I find myself with a `button` whose background color I need to change based on the value of the item selected.

I can get the hex value of the color from the item selected. The `<button>` and the `<select>` will be siblings, so I am using that relationship to iterate, with the intention of stopping when I find this button.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var this_color = $(this).val();

    $(this).siblings().each(function(i, elem) {

        if (elem.is(":button")) {
            elem.css('background-color', this_color);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

But this throws and error

> Uncaught TypeError: elem.is is not a function

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `elem` is a plain node object, you have to convert it as a jquery object to make use of `.is()`

```
if($(elem).is(":button")) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', this_color);
```

Since you are using `.each()` to iterate over the jquery element collection you can use `$(this)` instead of receiving the `element` explicitly as a parameter,

```
 $(this).siblings().each(function() {
   var _this = $(this);
   if(_this.is(":button")){
    _this.css('background-color', this_color);
    return false;
   }
 });
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! (I'll accept as soon as SO lets me).

Comment: @Randall Glad to help! :)